# Multiple Web Servers over a Single IP, Using Apache as a Reverse Proxy

Tags: apache-httpd, tomcat, http-proxy, reverse-proxy

How can I run multiple servers over a single IP, Using apache reverse proxy.

Basically I want to configure an apache proxy for atlassian products like follows:

```
https://jira.domain.com ProxyPass to http://jira.localhost:8080
https://confluence.domain.com ProxyPass to http://jira.localhost:8080
https://crowd.domain.com ProxyPass to http://crowd.localhost:8080
```

using a wildcard (star) ssl certificate.

Comment: Please tell us what was done and how might we enlighten your Unix path. See also our FAQ. This group is about aiding questions in Linux knowledge, not writing full tutorials / doing complex consulting for free. I would recommend doing well defined and single questions.

Answer (score -1):

You will need a DNS name for each site ([afrado dns](https://freedns.afraid.org/)), then you need to add vhost (virtual host), for each, then get a tls certificate form [lets encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) (set up automated renewal scripts). Don't forget to test after each step.

However nginx will be better than Apache (Apache is vulnerable to slow loris Denial of service attack, if not fronted by a proxy).